# Paypal Plus success data

Tags: angular, paypal-plus

I'm using Paypal Plus in my angular Project. Everything thing works fine.

How can I recognize that the payment was made successfully? Which data must I save in my database. In short which data am I waiting for in success?

```
<div id="payments-container"></div>
```

---

```
export class PaypalComponent implements OnInit {
  paypalConfig = {
    env: 'sandbox',
    client: {
      sandbox: 'ATvgtyEZznsHf...',
      production: '<insert production client id>'
    },
    style: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      label: 'pay',
      size: 'responsive',
      shape: 'rect',
      color: 'gold'
    },
    commit: true,
    payment: (data, actions) => {
      return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {
          transactions: [{
            amount: {
              total: 10.5,
              currency: "EUR",
            }
          }]
        }
      });
    },
    onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
      return actions.payment.execute().then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
        console.log('data', data);
        console.log('actions', actions);
      });
    },
    onCancel: (data, actions) => {
      console.log('Canceled!');
    }
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    paypal.Button.render(this.paypalConfig, '#payments-container');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#3-execute-the-payment):

> A successful response returns confirmation of the transaction, with the approved state and a transaction ID. See the complete list of [response values](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_execute) in the Payments API Reference.

Have a look at the [response docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment-execute-response) specifically:

> **id** string
>
> The ID of the payment. Read only.
>
> **intent** enum
>
> The payment intent. Value is: sale. Makes an immediate
>   payment. authorize. Authorizes a payment for capture later. order.
>   Creates an order. Possible values: sale, authorize, order.
>
> **payer** object
>
> The source of the funds for this payment. Payment method
>   is PayPal Wallet payment or bank direct debit.
>
> **application_context** object
>
> Use the application context resource to customize payment flow
>   experience for your buyers.
>
> **transactions** array (contains the transaction object)
>
> An array of payment-related
>   transactions. A transaction defines what the payment is for and who
>   fulfills the payment. For update and execute payment calls, the
>   transactions object accepts the amount object only.
>
> **state** enum
>
> The state of the payment,
>   authorization, or order transaction. Value is:
>
> - created. The
>     transaction was successfully created.
> - approved. The customer approved
>     the transaction. The state changes from created to approved on
>     generation of the sale_id for sale transactions, authorization_id for
>     authorization transactions, or order_id for order transactions.
> - failed. The transaction request failed. Read only.
>
> Possible values: created, approved, failed.
>
> **experience_profile_id** string
>
> The PayPal-generated ID for the
>   merchant's payment experience profile. For information, see create web
>   experience profile. note_to_payer string A free-form field that
>   clients can use to send a note to the payer. Maximum length: 165.
>
> **redirect_urls** object
>
> A set of redirect URLs that you provide for
>   PayPal-based payments.
>
> **failure_reason** enum
>
> The reason code for a
>   payment failure. Read only.
>
> Possible values: UNABLE_TO_COMPLETE_TRANSACTION,
>   INVALID_PAYMENT_METHOD, PAYER_CANNOT_PAY, CANNOT_PAY_THIS_PAYEE,
>   REDIRECT_REQUIRED, PAYEE_FILTER_RESTRICTIONS.
>
> **create_time** string
>
> The date and time when the payment was created, in
>   Internet date and time format. Read only.
>
> **update_time** string
>
> The date and time when the payment was updated, in
>   Internet date and time format. Read only.
>
> **links** array (contains the link_description object)
>
> An array of request-related HATEOAS links. Read only.

You'll definitely be looking for the `state` to be `approved`.

Depending on your auditing needs, you may wish to save any or all of the other fields. id, intent, payer, transactions, and failure_reason at minimum are all probably worth considering.